# Django Validation - Use Parent field validator and have subclass provide values

Tags: python, django, class, validation, inheritance

I have an abstract Parent model, and the subclasses inherit a field that has a validator. The validator takes in a list, and I would like each child to provide it's own list to validate against. I have something like this. Is there a way to do this? Am I over complicating it?

app1.py

```
@deconstrutible
class ValidateInList():
   def __init__(self, valid_items):
      self.valid_items = valid_items
   
   def __call__(self, value):
      if value not in self.valid_items:
         raise ValidationError()

class Parent(models.Model):
   field = models.CharField(max_length=20, validators=[ValidateInList(something)])

   class Meta:
      abstract = True
```

app2.py

```
class Child1(Parent):
   child_valid_items = [x,y,z] # would take the value of 'something' in Parent class

class Child2(Parent):
   child_valid_items = [a,b,c] # would take the value of 'something' in Parent class
```

Comment: My suggestion is: keep this type of validation in the forms. It seems like the `forms.ChoiceField` ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/fields/#choicefield)) might be a good solution for this.

Comment: Why not set the [`choices`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#choices) option on the field rather than defining your own validator? I think you may have to redefine the field on every subclass with custom choices if you don't want to create a complex and potentially hard to maintain solution

Comment: I'm updating old code and I was trying not to do anything that caused any migrations to be made right now, but ***choices*** might just be the way to go. Thanks.